Can we emulate / virtualize Android 14 by KostaKANG with AVD or qemu-system-arm on X64 ? Is there some difference?
Recently I've bought the RaspBerry Pi 4 and I've installed Android 14 AOSP by KostaKANG on it. It works well. But this has been only an intermediate step to reach another goal : try to emulate / virtualize with decent performances that version of Android on my PC (Intel cpu I9-I990K + nVidia 2080ti). I'm googling to understand how can I reach the goal. I see that basically I have only two options.

using qemu-system-arm : but in this case Android will be so slow that will be not usable at all ?

using the qemu used on the Android Virtual Device,that has been patched by Google,that's faster and in this case I can also use the graphic acceleration ? Please give a look at this post :


Run Android app in qemu-arm?
I don't understand if with the option 2 I can run the arm64 version of Android on my X64 PC.
Anyway all the links reported here :
https://web.archive.org/web/20171220070138/http://www.linaro.org/blog/core-dump/running-64bit-android-l-qemu/
are dead. Is still possible to do it ?
Please don't talk to me about Android X86,I'm not interested. Thank you.
Before to try,I want to gather some basic informations to understand if I can do it. Otherwise I will lose only my time.

HW-based virtualization virtualizes the same architecture, so x86-on-x86 or ARM-on-ARM. Emulation or SW-based virtualization can emulate/virtualize anything but it will be slower, especially for emulating a whole platform as complex as a mobile phone and its OS. You can't get around this. Since you don't want to use the x86 port, it's game over.
